# Including a header in multiple headers in my C++ code

Tags: c++, header, header-files, duplicate-symbol, numerical-recipes

I am trying to include a header file from the book [Numerical Recipes](https://github.com/blackstonep/Numerical-Recipes) in my code. The header files I have to include are the nr3.hpp and the interp_1d.hpp. The `interp_1d` needs the definitions of `nr3` in order to work.

I will write some of the code that appears on interp_1d.hpp so that you get an idea of what I am dealing with with the interp_1d code:

```
struct Base_interp{
...
};
Int Base_interp::locate(const Doub x){
...
}
...
Doub BaryRat_interp::interp(Doub x){
...
}
```

There are no header guards in this header file. As a result when I try to input it in multiple other header files I get the error "66 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64".

The structure of my code is the following:

```
myPulse.hpp:
#include "nr3.hpp"
#include "interp_1d.hpp"

calc1.hpp:
#include "myPulse.hpp"

calc2.hpp:
#include "myPulse.hpp"

main.cpp:
#include "myPulse.hpp"
#include "calc1.hpp"
#include "calc2.hpp"
#include "nr3.hpp"
#include "interp_1d.hpp"
```

I don't know how to overcome this issue. I want to be able to use the interp_1d.hpp functions in more than one part of the code. I tried including header guards, but this didn't work:

```
#ifndef Interp_1d
#define Interp_1d

#endif
```

Does anyone know how I use the interp_1d header in multiple other headers without this error occurring?

Comment: How did the preprocessor guards not work? When you tried that, what error(s) did you get?

Comment: Sounds like you need to use `inline` on the functions are *defined* (not just *declared*) in the header files, or move the definitions to a .cpp file.

Comment: @Chris I got the same error as before, it didn't change anything. If you have a look at the Numerical recipes website, many headers are a bit weird, with no guards. I don't know why that is

Comment: @FredLarson Right so I prefer not to change the functions themselves, but I will if I have to. 
If I include the header in the .cpp file of the class myPulse.cpp, I can successfully use it with no issue. However, after this I can't use it in a different .cpp file. I want to be able to use it in multiple .cpp files if possible

Comment: Hi Adrian, thank you for the fast reply. I forgot to mention in my question that the myPulse.hpp, calc1.hpp and calc2.hpp all have guards.

However, I will give the solution you provided with the myNumRec.hpp a try and see if it fixes the issue.

Comment: I have the Second Edition of "Numerical Recipes in C++" (old-fashioned, paper version only) and the header files listed in Appendix A and Appendix B all have header guards.

Comment: @AdrianMole Do you have a link to that? Hoppefully that would solve this issue

Comment: As I said, it's a paper (printed) version - so no link. Also, I'm not sure that the repo you linked is an official version, or if you should even be including the 'private' headers there in your source code.

Comment: There seems to be some confusion here over what these *"66 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64"* are and how they are included in your project. I shall delete my answer (for now) and maybe undelete/modify it if you can clarify your issue(s).

Comment: @AdrianMole I will clarify as best as I understand it. I include interp_1d.hpp in the header file myPulse.hpp. Then I include myPulse.hpp in both calc1.hpp and calc2.hpp. Finally I include all 3 myPulse.hpp, calc1.hpp and calc2.hpp in main.cpp. 
This leads to the contents of interp_1d being included 3 times and returning an error. Adding guards in interp_1d.hpp doesn't fix the error. What did solve the issue temporarily, is instead of including interp_1d in the myPulse.hpp I included it in the myPulse.cpp. However, when I tried to then include interp_1d in main the same error occured again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with a single file (or for brevity for books), some code can be simplified, but making multi-file case wrong.

In your case, header guards are missing, and `inline` are missing (or a cpp file to put definition).

So you cannot use them as-is.

You have either:

- split code for header/cpp file:

  ```
  // interp_1d.hpp
  #pragma once // or include guards
  struct Base_interp{
  //...
  };
  ```

  ```
  //interp_1d.cpp
  #include "interp_1d.hpp"
  Int Base_interp::locate(const Doub x){
  //...
  }

  Doub BaryRat_interp::interp(Doub x){
  //...
  }
  ```
- or put extra `inline`/`static` (not always enough/possible though (globals for example)) and header guard.

  ```
  // interp_1d.hpp
  #pragma once // or include guards
  struct Base_interp{
  //...
  };

  inline Int Base_interp::locate(const Doub x){
  //...
  }

  inline Doub BaryRat_interp::interp(Doub x){
  //...
  }
  ```

Comment: I see, I will try spliting it into header/cpp first. This looks promising thank you. If it doesn't work I will try inline method. Will let you know when I give them both a try
So generally speaking, structures should be included in the header file while all other functions should be in the cpp code?

Comment: splitting is the way to go, if you can, and indeed definition goes in cpp files while declaration goes in header.

Comment: Yes splitting solved the issue! I've been trying to solve this for 4 days! Thanks a lot for that. So apparently the Numerical Recipes header files have both the .cpp and .hpp content under the same file? Anyway thanks a lot!